# Android Studio - Copying image assets

Tags: android, android-studio

How can I copy the following type of image asset so that I can use it in a different project? I was able to copy and paste a single png but not the whole set of images.
[image]

This project is a sample project from [google codelabs](https://github.com/firebase/friendlychat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the resources are in separate dpi folders, you need to copy the folders over, which is not possible in the "Android" view. If you click on the drop down, you should be able to get to a "Project Files" view where you can copy all the folders. Alternatively, you can use an external file explorer to copy the folders.

Comment: I copied directories from "Project Files" view. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to navigate to where the project is stored. Once inside your application's folder, click app -> src -> main -> res -> drawable and select the images you wish to copy to another project. You can drag and drop these into your new android studio project or copy/paste them into the drawable folder in the new project's files as well.

Comment: This is how I do it too.